# Storing BigDecimal value in oracle DB with precision using ibatis/ mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, orm, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to store a BigDecimal object whose value is 1.0 , 2.0, etc and the DB is storing as 1, 2, 3 i.e. it is removing the decimal values.

I am using ibatis framework with java and the oracle db data type is Number(10,1), decimal(10,1).

Any clues on how to fix

Comment: The number 1 is equal to 1.0 so I'm not sure exactly what your issue is.  Perhaps when you convert the number to a string to be displayed you want to include a fixed number of decimal digits.  You can do that in the presentation layer with a `to_char` statement.

Comment: What happens when you try to store 1.5 or 2.3 etc?